# Как правильно написать числительные от четырëхзначных и более?

Tags: орфография, числительные

Как правильно пишутся числительные, содержащие более трëх нулей. Есть ли какое-то  правило по этому?

Как верно?

`100000`

`100 000`

`100.000`

`100,000`

И вообще, существует ли это правило? Или можно как угодно писать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как угодно писать не надо, особенно с точкой, а тем более с запятой (если это, конечно, не число 100 с тысячными долями).

Правильно с пробелом: *100 000*.

Вот один из [**ответов справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0):

> Числа в цифровой форме делят пробелами на группы (по три цифры) справа налево. Технические правила набора дают указание разбивать на группы числа только начиная с 5-значных (см. Наборные и фотонаборные процессы, М., 1983, п. 2.3.9), а «Основные математические обозначения (СЭВ PC 2625—70)» не делают исключения и для 4-значных чисел.
>
> Не разбиваются на группы цифры в числах, обозначающих номер (после знака номера), в марках машин и механизмов, в обозначениях нормативных документов (стандарты, техн. условия). Например: № 89954.
>
> Точку в пробелах между цифровыми группами многозначного числа ставить запрещается.
> (А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова, Справочник издателя и автора)